# Connection on Raspberry/Ubuntu as Access Point Wifi > Ethernet > Internet not going through

Tags: networking, wifi, access-point, hostapd

I managed to set up hostapd using `wifi-ap` [via Snap](https://snapcraft.io/install/wifi-ap/ubuntu) so my Raspberry Pi 4 creates a new Wifi Network `Ubuntu` that I can connect to. When I log in to that Raspberry via SSH using the new network, I can successfully do so, and when I ping a server on the internet from within the RPI, it can reach that server.

But when I connect to the Wifi that the Pi creates from my laptop, I don't have any access to the internet.

What am I missing to "bridge" the two interfaces so I can use the Raspberry Pi as a normal access point Wifi > Ethernet?

My `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

```
network:
        version: 2
        renderer: networkd
        ethernets:
                eth0:
                        dhcp4: true
                        dhcp6: true
```

my `/var/snap/wifi-ap/361/hostapd.conf`

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
ieee80211n=1
ssid=Ubuntu
auth_algs=1
utf8_ssid=1
hw_mode=g
# DTIM 3 is a good tradeoff between powersave and latency
dtim_period=3

# The wmm_* options are needed to enable AMPDU
# and get decent 802.11n throughput
# UAPSD is for stations powersave
uapsd_advertisement_enabled=1
wmm_enabled=1
wmm_ac_bk_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_bk_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_bk_aifs=7
wmm_ac_bk_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_bk_acm=0
wmm_ac_be_aifs=3
wmm_ac_be_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_be_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_be_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_be_acm=0
wmm_ac_vi_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vi_cwmin=3
wmm_ac_vi_cwmax=4
wmm_ac_vi_txop_limit=94
wmm_ac_vi_acm=0
wmm_ac_vo_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmin=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmax=3
wmm_ac_vo_txop_limit=47
wmm_ac_vo_acm=0
# Regulatory domain options
# Country code set to global
country_code=XX
# End reg domain options
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=*****************
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

my `netconfig` output

```
ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:c4:76:07:d8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.8.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.8.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe0d:47b2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd29:d2c5:be9d::d60  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fd29:d2c5:be9d:0:dea6:32ff:fe0d:47b2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether dc:a6:32:0d:47:b2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9251  bytes 3761308 (3.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7765  bytes 1113458 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 23558  bytes 3709615 (3.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23558  bytes 3709615 (3.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.60.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether dc:a6:32:0d:47:b3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 102  bytes 82620 (82.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found the answer!

Just unmask:

`systemctl unmask hostapd`

then

`systemctl enable hostapd`

And restart.

I hope it works for you, too.